# Why do we need a historyId when we can just check whether we have processed the (userId, messageId) tuple?

Tags: gmail-api

Currently my code checks whether we have seen the (userId,messageId) tuple before and stops fetching more new messages if it has. The historyId seems to be doing the same thing? I'm trying to understand the difference between the 2 approaches.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to get a message in Gmail, we use userId and messageId tuple using messages.get.

Where as in the Gmail interface the messages are displayed based on the historyId.

Hope that explains the main purpose of the historyId.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but I've been looking into this myself.

Getting a list of emails based on the historyId with Users.History.List will give you all changes since the passed historyId.  So if a label is added for example then it will be returned with the list.

Your approach is simply looking for new messages that have not been seen with Users.Messages.List.  Changes will not be returned with this approach - rather just new messages.